# how to move SharePoint 2010 workflows build using sp designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

how to move SharePoint 2010 workflows build using  sp designer 2010 from dev to production ? until now I have alwasy recreated that in prod environment , is there a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to export to visio then import it to poruction by following the mentioned steps below :

- In SharePoint Designer 2010, click on your completed List Workflow.
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for the completed List Workflow.
- Next, click on “Export to Visio”. Save the file as CompletedWorkflow.vwi or any preferred name.
- Then create a new “similar” list on the current site or on a new site collection.
- There is no way to import the exported visio into this new list.
- In SharePoint Designer 2010, click on this new list and then click on “List Workflow” to create a new workflow for this new list.
- Please make sure that you do not add any workflow steps!
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for this empty List Workflow.
- Then, click on “Export to Visio” and save this as EmptyWorkflow.vwi or any preferred name.
- Rename both the vwi files by adding “.zip” extension. The files should be CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip and EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- The objective is to replace the “workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml” file from the EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip into the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- It is likely that you cannot replace it directly. Copy the file out to the desktop and then copy the file into the other zipped folder.
- Remove the “.zip” extension from the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.
- With this, we have a working importable visio List Workflow.
- Back in the SharePoint Designer 2010, close all the workflow tabs.
- Click on the “Import from Visio” and select the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.

You have successfully export and import the List Workflow! [Ref](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wkng/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

There's not a simple way out of the box. There are articles about how to movie them with [Visio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/momalek/2012/04/22/solved-moving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows-between-sites/). The answer to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89813/would-it-be-possible-to-move-the-list-workflowsspd-to-another-site) goes through moving it and then replacing the List GUIDs. [This is the tutorial](https://mikessharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/moving-sharepoint-designer-workflows/) I usually refer to.

There are also 3rd party tools that make this easier. We've used DocAve.